# Could not find class oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer

Tags: android, oauth, signpost

I had to format and start over yesterday, and I'm trying to get my project up and running again.

I use the signpost library for OAuth authentication. I've imported my project and Eclipse gives me no errors in the text editor.  However, when I run my app and hit the oauth code, my app bombs with the following error:

```
04-25 15:07:04.485: E/dalvikvm(344): Could not find class 'oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer', referenced from method com.myapp.app.ws.WebService.addHeaders
```

The project seems to find the jar files just fine. They show up in the Java Build Path -> Libraries tab.

I'm not really sure what I'm missing here.  Ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My guess is that this error is related to ADT 17. Its expected to put the jars into the libs folder now. If you dont do that go to `configure build path`->`Order and Export`. Click the checkbox for your jar.

Comment: My jar files are directly inside the project's directory.  I have gone to Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export tab > and checked the library's files (two jars and a folder).  I then did a clean... and built the project.  Everything is now working.  Thank you.