# Creating PDF in Android

Tags: android, pdf

Can we create PDF file in android?

- I have Tried all Google Search.
- Also seen more examples on it.
- And i have tried this,

  ```
  File f=new File("/data/data/com.pdf/test1.pdf");  
  Log.d("test", "created");  
  Document document = new Document();  
  PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(f));  
  document.open();            
  document.addTitle("My first PDF");
  document.addSubject("Using iText");
  document.addKeywords("Java, PDF, iText");  
  document.addAuthor("Lars Vogel");
  document.addCreator("Lars Vogel");
  Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("This is left aligned text with indentation");
  paragraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
  paragraph.setIndentationLeft(50);
  document.add(paragraph);
  document.close();
  Toast.makeText(this, "Pdf Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  ```

But This Gives Error As ,

```
08-11 16:53:38.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2484): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 16:53:38.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2484): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:          com.itextpdf.text.Document
08-11 16:53:38.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2484):     at com.pdf.PDFReaderActivity.onCreate(PDFReaderActivity.java:28)
08-11 16:53:38.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2484):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
08-11 16:53:38.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2484):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-11 16:53:38.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2484):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
08-11 16:53:38.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2484):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
08-11 16:53:38.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2484):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-11 16:53:38.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2484):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
08-11 16:53:38.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2484):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-11 16:53:38.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2484):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-11 16:53:38.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2484):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-11 16:53:38.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2484):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 16:53:38.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2484):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-11 16:53:38.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2484):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-11 16:53:38.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2484):     at com .android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-11 16:53:38.446: E/AndroidRuntime(2484):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: do you have necessary permissions set in your manifest? like writing on external storage?

Comment: what is line no 28 in PdfReaderActivity??

Comment: @gabi: I have accessed from internal device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that the jar which contains the PdfWriter class got not exported into the apk file.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323069/could-not-find-class-oauth-signpost-commonshttp-commonshttpoauthconsumer/10323245#10323245) for a solution.