# Could not find class oauth.signpost.commonshttp.commonshttpoauthconsumer... again

Tags: android

[I've previously had this problem, and now I'm having it again.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323069/could-not-find-class-oauth-signpost-commonshttp-commonshttpoauthconsumer)

I've just updated the Android SDK/Plug-in and I am, once again, getting this error.

As you can see, this library is in my libs folder.

[image: jars in libs folder]

I also have it checked on Order and Export.

[image: order and export]

What have they changed now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by checking Android Private Libraries on Order and Export

Comment: Thanks worked, thank you.  However, it required a clean and rebuild before it did.  No idea why this was all the sudden mandatory.

Comment: Glad it worked. I think this will be the case from now on. Can you mark this post as answered? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add external jar to library; remove the commons-code.jar. Copy it into libs folder then add it as a library